# AWS SDK V2 for Java: Copy object greater than 5GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

How can I copy objects larger than 5GB using AWS SDK V2 for java?

Sample for V1 is available here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CopyingObjectsMPUapi.html

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to copy object with multipart in Java S3 SDK v2.

```java
    private final S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().build();

    public void copyObjectWithMultiPart() {

        String destBucketName = "destination-bucket";
        String destObjectKey = "destination-object-key";
        String sourceBucketName = "source-bucket";
        String sourceObjectKey = "source-object-key";

        // Initiate the multipart upload.
        CreateMultipartUploadRequest createMultipartUploadRequest = CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                .bucket(destBucketName)
                .key(destObjectKey)
                .build();

        CreateMultipartUploadResponse multipartUploadResponse = s3Client.createMultipartUpload(createMultipartUploadRequest);

        // Get the object size to track the end of the copy operation.
        HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(sourceBucketName)
                .key(sourceObjectKey)
                .build();
        long objectSize = s3Client.headObject(headObjectRequest).contentLength();

        // Copy the object using 5 MB parts.
        long partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        long bytePosition = 0;
        int partNum = 1;
        List<CompletedPart> etags = new ArrayList<>();
        while (bytePosition < objectSize) {
            // The last part might be smaller than partSize, so check to make sure
            // that lastByte isn't beyond the end of the object.
            long lastByte = Math.min(bytePosition + partSize - 1, objectSize - 1);

            // Copy this part.
            UploadPartCopyRequest uploadPartCopyRequest = UploadPartCopyRequest.builder()
                    .sourceBucket(sourceBucketName)
                    .sourceKey(sourceObjectKey)
                    .destinationBucket(destBucketName)
                    .destinationKey(destObjectKey)
                    .uploadId(multipartUploadResponse.uploadId())
                    .partNumber(partNum)
                    .copySourceRange(String.format("bytes=%d-%d", bytePosition, lastByte))
                    .build();

            UploadPartCopyResponse uploadPartCopyResponse = s3Client.uploadPartCopy(uploadPartCopyRequest);
            etags.add(
                    CompletedPart.builder()
                            .partNumber(partNum++)
                            .eTag(uploadPartCopyResponse.copyPartResult().eTag())
                            .build()
            );
            bytePosition += partSize;
        }

        // Complete the upload request to concatenate all uploaded parts and make the copied object available.
        CompletedMultipartUpload completedMultipartUpload = CompletedMultipartUpload.builder()
                .parts(etags)
                .build();

        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeMultipartUploadRequest =
                CompleteMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(destBucketName)
                        .key(destObjectKey)
                        .uploadId(multipartUploadResponse.uploadId())
                        .multipartUpload(completedMultipartUpload)
                        .build();

        s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(completeMultipartUploadRequest);
    }
```